# Load coordinates and colors of pixels in an image into an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

A usual way to load an image (PNG) of resolution mxn into an array is to use matplotlib.pyplot.imread(), which returns an array of dimension (m,n,4) (in RGBA case) whose [i,j,0] element is the value of RED of the (i,j)-th pixel.

However, in this case, I would like the array to contain also coordinates. In other words, I expect that the array is of dimension (mn, 6), whose [ij, 0] element is i, [ij, 1] is j and [ij, 2] is the value of RED of the (i,j)-th pixel, etc.

Though this could certainly be done by a loop, I wonder whether there is some array operations, which could be far more efficient than loop.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean, can you explain? I don’t know how to interpret the [ij, 0] notation.

Comment: @AMC The image has mn pixels. I want to have a two-dimension array A (i.e., a matrix), s.t., the k-th row of A contains data of the k-th pixel (in any ordering that you like). As the k-th pixel has 6 properties (in RGBA case): two coordinates and RGBA values, A should be of shape (mn, 6), and [k, 0], [k, 1] should be the coordinates, [k, 2] should be the value of RED, etc.

Comment: Ah alright that makes sense now!